# fade in and out pages

Tags: jquery, ajax, css-transitions

how is the fade in and out exactly achieved [here](http://www.sagmeisterwalsh.com/about/)? have a feeling the site is 'ajaxed' as well.

the fades occur on exit and entrance. smoothly done.

similar to [this](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2010/02/23/how-to-use-jquery-to-make-slick-page-transitions/) solution?

fade in can be done with css3 animations if i am not mistaken. could light js be used to trigger a hold and fadeout css anim on exit?

**update: just came across [this](https://github.com/dgileadi/zepto-page-transitions). seems great. any thoughts? how does it compare to the solution used int he first link?**

thanks!

Comment: A cursory glance suggests that behaviour is from http://www.sagmeisterwalsh.com/js/init.js

Answer (score 1):

Let's have simple example how you can do this with jQuery.

Below is the sample html and jQuery code for how to can do fadeIn and fadeOut with ajax.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function()
        {
            $("div#menu ul li a").click(function(e)
            {
                var href = $(this).attr('href');
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url : href,
                    dataType : 'html',
                    type    : 'get',
                    beforeSend : function()
                    {
                        //code before send request
                    },
                    success : function(htmlResponse)
                    {
                        $('#container').empty().html(htmlResponse).fadeIn('slow');
                    }
                });

            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="container"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

what i am doing in above example is created sample `html` with has `div` with `id menu` having three `li` tag having `link` to each it.

now i created assigned `jQuery click event` to those link and get their `href` attribute and send request to that `href` using `jQuery.ajax` .

Now on **successful response**, it will load all the result `html` inside `container` div which is created in `html.`

And you are done you can also add more animations to it but i kept it simple for understanding.